# CakePHP: keeping view files in same directory

Tags: html, cakephp

For `controller_A`'s views, I currently use `$this->element('repeatedly_used_html');` in the `element` folder for some `.ctp` files that are used more than once. However, some of the files in the `element` folder are entirely used for one controller, and the file are  unorganized in the `element` folder.

So, for exmaple, `controller_A` has views that use files from the `element` folder. I would like these `.ctp` files for controller A's views to be contained in the `app/views/A`.. is there way to invoke a call similar to `$this->element('repeatedly_used_html');` that will allow me to keep files the folder `app/views/controller_A`? I would like to avoid writing a very long `.ctp` file.

Comment: maybe all you need is using subfolders in elements folder [try this link for more info](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cake-php/mh-wvqlvIWE/-vrloKJSLmAJ)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using CakePHP 1.3 based on your directory structure. If this is the case, you can do this by simply using the `render()` method instead of `element()`. This will render a template using the current view path (in this case, the controller you're in).

```
echo $this->render('repeatedly_used_html', false);
```

The second parameter is the layout, which we set to `false` to make sure the whole layout isn't rendered along with the view.

Comment: Hey, jeremyharris, thanks. That works. I am wondering, however, what some of the differences are for the two methods. I have posted another question, if you're interested in answering or know the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940669/cakephp-this-render-vs-this-element

Answer (score 2):

```
echo $this->element( 'subfoldername/viewfile' );
```

Then create the subfoldername directory in your elements folder.