# CakePHP 1.3: $this->render() vs $this->element()

Tags: php, cakephp

Besides the location of the view files, what are some differences between using (I'm using these calls in view files for small HTML codes that are used in multiple view files)

`echo $this->render('some_view_file', false)` vs `echo $this->element('some_view_file')`?

I had been using the `$this->element()` for a while because all of the tutorials and guides I've read uses this method, but my element folder has too many files for different controllers. I recently found out I can use `$this->render()` and keep the view files in their respective folders in `app/view/controller_name`, which makes file organization easier and cleaner.

Comment: where do you use those? in the view or controller? that itself should answer your question...

Comment: I'm not sure there's a good answer to this question. If you're interested in the subtle differences, I'd suggest reading the code itself. It's very readable. There's not a huge difference between the two, except that `View::render()` automatically sets view vars, assumes the layout and view paths, etc.

Comment: Also keep in mind the OP was using CakePHP 1.3 at the time of this question.

Comment: Not sure if this works in 1.3, but I tend to create subdirectories with the Elements directory to organise my element templates. Then when I call the element I use $this->element('subdirectory/template.ctp').

Comment: drmonkeyninja, yeah, I've read a few posts where people recommended using the subdirectory structure. It sounds pretty good.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**$this->render()**

`$this->render()` is code for your Controller.  It tells your Controllers action which file to render.  By default, you should not need to use this - if you name your View files correctly and place them in the correct folder, they will render automatically.  (there are cases where you will use it, but - it's not for use in every action)

**$this->element()**

`$this->element()` is code for within your View.  It is used to load small pieces of code that you'd like to be able to use in multiple places in a view, or in multiple views.

According to the CakePHP book, an "element" is :

> smaller, reusable bits of view code. Elements are usually rendered
>   inside of views.

So you should be using Views, not Elements as your main "page" files, **and within your views, use `$this->element()` to pull in reusable chunks of code.**

Comment: I have made some edits to my OP. I am using `element()` for small view codes that are used more than once.

Comment: Yep - use elements per answer.